# git stash, avoiding merging unstaged changes to the staging area

Tags: git

In my working directory I have some changes in the staging area and some other changes which are unstaged. When I run:

```
    git stash -u
    git stash apply
```

unstaged changes are added to the staging area, as if I've run `git add *`. Or vice versa, staged changes become unstaged changes.

In other words, before the stash the situation of the working directory is:

```
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
    modified:   test1.txt
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   test2.txt
```

then I run:

```
    git stash -u
    git stash apply
```

and, after running the previous commands, the situation is this:

```
$ git stash apply
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   test1.txt
    modified:   test2.txt
```

Is there a way to apply a stash so that the separation among staged changes and unstaged changes is preserved?

Comment: Stash usually makes 2 (and sometimes 3) commits under the hood, covering both your working directory and stage.  So the question is, which part of the stash do you want to apply, or, alternatively, which part of the stash do you _not_ want applied here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I apply only a part of a stash?

Comment: Please answer my question above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I miss a piece of information for answering your question: what these 2 or 3 commits consist of?

Comment: Yes, I think you are looking for `git stash apply --index`.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Marco Luzzara, the command needed is:

```
git stash apply --index
```